# Had time to think of one when we were snowed in yesterday

Tags: riddle, visual

The images below are connected by a single word:

[image: Cardboard Box]

[image: A Horn]

[image: A Nebula with a Distinctive Shape]

[image: A Particular Type of Tree]

[image: A Bow String]

[image: A Lace Doily]

What is the word and what are the connections?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does this fit

> Shoe

The images representing

> [Shoebox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoebox) 
>
>  Shoehorn
>
>  Horseshoe - from the Horsehead nebula
>
>  Gumshoe - from the gum tree and a slang name for a detective
>
>  Shoestring
>
>  Shoe lace

The title

> Snowshoes

Comment: Quick as always Tom +1

Comment: For #4, **[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoe_tree)** is also a thing.